# Accessing view from multiple Fragment instantiations in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

It was tricky to write a title for this. What I currently do, is to reuse one Fragment class to create a multitude of ListFragments in a ViewPager.
The layout of the ListFragments are all the same so having just one layout and one Fragment as a base seems like a sound choice.
However, I'd like to be able to access each Fragment's views, in order to set some per-Fragment values, such as a title, a name and whatnot. I have an issue with this and it's the fact that whenever I try to access a TextView by overriding a Fragment's onViewCreated-method, it seems to me that the only Fragment getting updated is the first one in the chain.

Now, what I do to instantiate and connect the Fragments is this:

```
private void initPager() {
    mFragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    int[] listIds = 3;
    for(int i = 0; i < listIds.length; i++) {
        Fragment fragment = new ListsFragment(listIds[i]);
        mFragments.add(fragment);
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    for(int i = 0; i < mFragments.size(); i++) {
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.viewpager, mFragments.get(i));
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    mPagerAdapter = new ListsPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, mFragments);
    mPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
}
```

The Fragment onViewCreated() code is this:

```
    @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    TextView textListTitle = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text_list_title);
            String title = "test";
    textListTitle.setText(listTitle);
}
```

When looking at logs I see that each Fragment is instantiated separatly, going through the lifecycle of each in succession. However, the only Fragment getting the "test"-string is the first one.

What am I missing?

Comment: There's no reason to use a `Vector` here... just use an `ArrayList` :)

Comment: Also... this won't compile: `int[] listIds = 3;`... so I honestly have no idea lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be instantiating your `Fragment`s in a `FragmentPagerAdapter` of some sort.

Comment: Entirely correct. I have since included a FragmentPagerAdapter to take care of this properly.